# Export CSV to MySQL through PHP

Tags: php, mysql, csv

Following is my PHP Code:

```
$handle = fopen($_FILES['filename']['tmp_name'], "r");

while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
    $import="INSERT into info(tazkira,gender,province,category,clin,training) values('$data[0]','$data[1]','$data[2]','$data[3]','$data[4]','$data[5]')";

    mysql_query($import) or die(mysql_error());
}

fclose($handle);

print "Import done";
```

I have around 10 MBs of CSV file and I upload it to MySQL through PHP in my local XAMP server, but it takes around 10 to 15 mins. I have this application that will go online, so it's difficult for each use to wait 10 mins to transfer CSV to MySQL. Currently, I use MySQL-Front, which takes only 1 second. Please let me know how to speed up the CSV to MySQL through PHP.

Comment: If it's available to you, https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mysqlimport.html is the fastest way of loading CSV files into MySQL that I'm aware of.

Answer (score 0):

```
if(isset($_POST["Import"]))
{

$host='localhost'; // Host Name.

$db_user= '****'; //User Name

$db_password= '****';

$db= '*****'; // Database Name.

$conn=mysql_connect($host,$db_user,$db_password) or die (mysql_error());
mysql_select_db($db) or die (mysql_error());

$csv = $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"];

if($_FILES["file"]["size"] > 0)

{    
$csvfile = fopen($csv, 'r');

$field_csv = array();

$i = 0;

while (($csv_data = fgetcsv($csvfile, 1024, ",")) !== FALSE)
{

    if($i==0) { $i++; continue; }  // to exclude first line in the csv file.

    $field_csv['list_catagory_id'] = $csv_data[0];  // first csv field
    $field_csv['list_name'] = $csv_data[1]; // second csv field
    $field_csv['list_tamil'] = $csv_data[2]; // third csv field
    $field_csv['list_hindi'] = $csv_data[3]; // third csv field
    $field_csv['list_botanical'] = $csv_data[4]; 
    $field_csv['list_image'] = $csv_data[5]; 
    $field_csv['list_cook_time'] = $csv_data[6]; 
    $field_csv['list_summary'] = $csv_data[7]; 
    $field_csv['list_ingredients'] = $csv_data[8]; 
    $field_csv['list_instruction'] = $csv_data[9]; 

    $query = "INSERT INTO list SET list_catagory_id = '".$field_csv['list_catagory_id']."',list_name = '".$field_csv['list_name']."',list_tamil = '".$field_csv['list_tamil']."',list_hindi = '".$field_csv['list_hindi']."',list_botanical = '".$field_csv['list_botanical']."',list_image = '".$field_csv['list_image']."',list_cook_time = '".$field_csv['list_cook_time']."',list_summary = '".$field_csv['list_summary']."',list_ingredients = '".$field_csv['list_ingredients']."',list_instruction = '".$field_csv['list_instruction']."' ";
    mysql_query($query);    
}

fclose($csvfile);

}

echo "Data Successfully Imported To Table!!";

}
}
```